# No view found for id for fragment GameActivityFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use fragments but I'm having a trouble when I want to dynamically add or replace one. When I do, I'm getting this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0074 (com.hang:id/fragment_game2_id) for fragment GameActivityFragment{254a4f5 #1 id=0x7f0c0074}
```

Here's what I'm doing:

- First, I launch an Activity called "GameActivity" that contains a fragment view using a layout (fragment_game) with only a single button:

  ```
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/fragment"
      android:name="com.hang.activities.GameActivityFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game" />
  ```
- In "GameActivity", I'm calling "setOnClickListener" to change the fragment. In "OnClick", here's my code:

  ```
          Bundle b = new Bundle();
          b.putString("level", "01");
          GameActivityFragment fragment = new GameActivityFragment();
          fragment.setArguments(b);
          FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.replace(R.id.fragment_game2_id, fragment)
                  .addToBackStack(null)
                  .commit();`
  ```

Fragment_game2_id is identifying a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_game2_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.hang.activities.GameActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_game">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Game Activity fragment!!" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

In my class "GameActivityFragment" that extends Fragment, I'm only overriding OnCreateView:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);
    }
```

That's when I'm clicking on the button that I'm having the error above. I don't understand because I have a view with this id (fragment_game2_id). I also tried to put this code into "OnCreateView" from GameActivityFragment, after inflating the view but same result, even by replacing into OnCreateView the "GetSupportFragmentManager" by "GetFragmentManager" or "GetChildFragmentManager". I also looked for answers in other similar questions here but I haven't managed to fix the problem.

To explain what I want to do: I have my MainActivity displaying a fragment with several buttons corresponding to different levels of my game. By clicking on one of them, I'm launching a new Activity called GameActivity with a fragment in it. The fragment would first display all sublevels and when the user click on one of them, I want to change the fragment to start the game. When done, the fragment would replace the game layout with the previous layout displaying all sublevels so that the user can click on the next sublevel.

**EDIT ::** My Fragment_game layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.hang.activities.GameActivityFragment"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Game Activity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

That's it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working now! Only one little problem, the button still appears in front of the new view. Is it because R.id.fragment is not the good one to replace but another one?

Comment: Could you also be able to enlighten me on my other issue? I can't find why the older view is still displayed :p

Comment: What did you mean by your old view?

Comment: The button which allows me to replace the fragment still appears on top of the new fragment's layout. Here's what I have: [image of the problem](http://i.imgur.com/Zxz7ZkD.png).

The violet layout is the layout of the new fragment and on top of it, the button is still there. :/

Comment: Post the layout fragment_game

Comment: In my GameActivityFragment, I'm using a condition to use a layout that I put into a Bundle:

View v;

        if (getArguments() != null)
            v = inflater.inflate(getArguments().getInt("layout"), container, false);
        else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);

        return v;
This layout is fragment_game2 which contains only a TextView for now.

Comment: Please open another SO question so that others can answer your question too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```